# why this Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context, react-lifecycle

can anyone help me with this as not working properly maybe there might become a problem in context API I am new to it, please help I think I am missing something in my lifecycle hook, I have tried to use component will mount instead of useEffect but still it's not working? Maybe I am missing something very small please help me with the code.
[

```js
const EventsPage = () => {
    const [creating, setCreating] = useState(false);
    const [events, setEvents] = useState([]);
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
    const [selectedEvent, setSelectedEvent] = useState(null);
    var isActive = true;
    const context = useContext(AuthContext);

    const { titleElRef, priceElRef, dateElRef, descriptionElRef } = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchEvents();
        return () => {
            isActive = false;
        };
    }, []);

        const event = { title, price, date, description };
    return (
        <Fragment>
            {context.token && (
                <div className="events-control">
                    <p>Share your own Events!</p>
                    <button className="btn" onClick={setCreating(true)}>
                        Create Event
                    </button>
                </div>
            )}  
        </Fragment>
    );
};

export default EventsPage;
```

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2DA8b.png)

Comment: That's a lot of code and a lot of dependencies. Are you sure all of this is needed to reproduce the problem? Check out [mcve] for guidance on writing a focused question. Thanks!

Comment: The first thing I would tell you to do is strip out everything that is not relevant to the problem. Just copying a whole component over is adding too much noise that makes it way harder for others to help you. What have you tried so far yourself to fix the problem?

Comment: @ggorlen you were quicker ;-)

Comment: I can see an error on your onClick button. it should be `<button className="btn" onClick={() => setCreating(true)}>`, not `onClick={setCreating(true)}` since the latter would invoke `setCreating` right away

Comment: `const { titleElRef, priceElRef, dateElRef, descriptionElRef } = useRef(null);` each of these variables will be undefined since the object returned doesn't contain any of these properties. you should create 4 `useRef`, one for each. like `const titleElRef = useRef(null)`

Comment: @buzatto it solved my problem ty so much